# Better safe get from an array in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to get first argument for `main` method that is optional, something like this:

```
val all = args(0) == "all"
```

However, this would fail with exception if no argument is provided.

Is there any one-liner simple method to set `all` to `false` when args[0] is missing; and not doing the common `if-no-args-set-false-else...` thingy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general case you can use lifting:

```
 args.lift(0).map(_ == "all").getOrElse(false)
```

Or even (thanks to @enzyme):

```
 args.lift(0).contains("all")
```

Comment: `args.lift(0).contains("all")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `headOption` and `fold` (on Option):

```
val all = args.headOption.fold(false)(_ == "all")
```

Of course, as @mohit pointed out, `map` followed by `getOrElse` will work as well.

If you really need indexed access, you could pimp a `get` method on any `Seq`:

```
implicit class RichIndexedSeq[V, T <% Seq[V]](seq: T) {
  def get(i: Int): Option[V] =
    if (i < 0 || i >= seq.length) None
    else Some(seq(i))
}
```

However, if this is really about arguments, you'll be probably better off, handling arguments in a fold:

```
case class MyArgs(n: Int = 1, debug: Boolean = false,
    file: Option[String] = None)

val myArgs = args.foldLeft(MyArgs()) {
  case (args, "-debug") =>
    args.copy(debug = true)
  case (args, str) if str.startsWith("-n") =>
    args.copy(n = ???) // parse string
  case (args, str) if str.startsWith("-f") =>
    args.copy(file = Some(???) // parse string
  case _ => 
    sys.error("Unknown arg")
}

if (myArgs.file.isEmpty)
  sys.error("Need file")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foldLeft` with initial `false` value:

```
val all = (false /: args)(_ | _ == "all")
```

But be careful, `One Liners` can be difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work assuming `args(0)` returns `Some` or `None`:

`val all = args(0).map(_ == "all").getOrElse(false)`

Comment: Last time I checked, `List` does not have a `get` method either.

Comment: args.lift(0).map(...)